# Cauchy's real line and math philosophy till XIX

Tags: mathematics, mathematicians, philosophy-of-science

I have to write an essay concerning philosophy of mathematics until the end of XIX century. I've heard that the reason why the Cauchy's theorem (if continuous functions $fn→f$ then $f$ is continuous too) is wrong nowadays is the fact that his real numbers line (number system) was different then the modern one. It is indeed a very interesting topic but I couldn't find anything specific about it. Could you direct me to some sources or suggest a different topic?

Comment: See Greg Graviton's answer at http://mathoverflow.net/questions/67879/what-are-examples-of-theorems-which-were-once-valid-then-became-invalid-as/67915#67915. The sense in which Cauchy's "real number line" is different is that he included infinitesimals when he did calculus.

Comment: 1. Questions on homework assignment are not welcome on this site. 2. I would recommend you to read the work of Bolzano for the beginning of research on your topic. One modern work specifically related to your question is Imre Lakatos, Proofs and refutations, very last chapter.